# Conditionally select values from an array in a nested JSON string in a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am struggling to conditionally extract values from a nested JSON string in the Mysql table.

```
{"users": [{"userId": "10000001", "userToken": "11000000000001", "userTokenValidity": 1}, {"userId": "10000002", "userToken": "12000000000001", "userTokenValidity": 1}, {"userId": "10000003", "userToken": "13000000000001", "userTokenValidity": 0}]}
```

I want to select a userToken but only if the userTokenValidity is 1. So in this example only "11000000000001" and "12000000000001" should get selected.

This will extract the whole array ... how should I filter the result?

```
SELECT t.my_column->>"$.users" FROM my_table t;
```

Comment: You need to use JSON_TABLE(), which means you need to use MySQL 8.0. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: @BillKarwin I am using the 8.0.29 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CAST(value AS CHAR) output
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.data, '$.users[*]' COLUMNS (value JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
WHERE value->>'$.userTokenValidity' = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4876ec22a9df4f6d2e75a476a02a2615